# VBA Excel command doesn't work when called with Shell, but works when copy-pasted to cmd directly

Tags: excel, vba, shell, cmd

I'm trying to run a program with an input file.

```
Dim command, cfx5_exe_path, cfx_file_folder, cfx_file_name As String

command = cfx5_exe_path & " -cfx " & cfx_file_folder & cfx_file_name & ".cfx "
Shell command
```

so it gives an error.
the resulting value of the *command* in the debugger is

```
"c:\"Program Files"\"ANSYS Inc"\v150\CFX\bin\cfx5pre.exe -cfx c:\Users\Username\Arbeit\Programming\A321_tail_flow.cfx"
```

If I copy-paste that into windows *cmd* directly and remove first/last quotation signs, then it works perfectly.
What is the problem with *Shell*?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says:

> If the Shell function successfully executes the named file, it returns the task ID of the started program. The task ID is a unique number that identifies the running program. If the Shell function can't start the named program, an error occurs.

and it gives a small example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim RetVal
    Dim command As String
    command = "C:\WINDOWS\CALC.EXE"
    RetVal = Shell(command, 1)
End Sub
```

Here I get `Error 53: file not found` as calc on Windows 7 resides somewhere else. Do you get this error?

Providing the right path to calc starts the program and returns a unique ID.

However, quoting a part of the correct path will throw the error:

```
    command = "C:\WINDOWS\""SYSTEM32""\CALC.EXE"
```

but quoting the full path does not:

```
    command = """C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CALC.EXE"""
```

So you must remove all embedded quotes and then quote the full path once.

Comment: Yes, I get the same Error 53. Why did you qoute system32? I quoted Program Files as there is a space in the folder name.

Comment: I quoted it just as a try. It seems it only accepts quotes around the full path when there is a space in _any_ part. So quoting only the parts with a space leads to the error.